# Do Civs on the same team share abilities?

Tags: civilization-5

Does the ability for each nation count for the other? Example: If France and Aztecs are on the same team, if Napoleon kills a barbarian does he gain culture because of the Aztecs ability due to them being on the same team? (In this case we can assume they both do not have the Honor tree invested into.)

Answer (score 4):

No, bonuses and policies are not shared between team members. Only science is shared.

Comment: Also declarations of war, city-state discovery, and map vision.

Comment: And score I suppose.